# How do I find out Groovy runtime version from a running app?

Tags: groovy

I need to be able to find out the version of Groovy runtime via a groovy script.
How do I do it? The examples I found on the net show a way, but apparently it has been deprecated and removed in the latest version.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

This should work:

```
println GroovySystem.version
```

So long as you are on Groovy 1.6.6+

Before that, it was:

```
println org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.version
```

But that's been removed from later versions of Groovy

Answer (score 5):

To improve slightly on [tim_yates' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18876543/1580487), here's the universal code to get Groovy version:

```
public String getGroovyVersion() {
        try {
                return org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.version
        }
        catch (Throwable ignore) { }
        return GroovySystem.version
}

println getGroovyVersion()
```