# Iterating a groovy list in Jenkins Pipeline DSL

Tags: groovy, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I have a simple groovy list in my Pipeline that adds some maps:

```
def componentList = []

def componentMapEntry1 = [:]
componentMapEntry1['componentName']="Dashboard_Core"
componentList << componentMapEntry1

def componentMapEntry2 = [:]
componentMapEntry2['componentName']="Dashboard_Equities"
componentList << componentMapEntry2

def cme3 = [:]
cme3["componentName"] = "home"
componentList << cme3
```

When job is executed, I validate size

```
echo "size of list "+componentList.size()
```

...

```
[Pipeline] echo
size of list 3
```

I can print it out the list

```
println componentList
```

...

```
[Pipeline] echo
[{componentName=Dashboard_Core}, {componentName=Dashboard_Equities}, {componentName=home}]
```

I can do a for loop and iterate the list

```
for (i = 0; i <componentList.size(); i++) {
    println componentList[i]
}
```

...

```
[Pipeline] echo
{componentName=Dashboard_Core}
[Pipeline] echo
{componentName=Dashboard_Equities}
[Pipeline] echo
{componentName=home}
```

So far all's well.

Problem comes in when I try to use standard groovy iterator:

```
componentList.each {
    println "adding "+it.componentName
}
```

In this case I only get the first element

```
[Pipeline] echo
adding Dashboard_Core
```

Why would I only get the first element here? I've tried this several times and using .each() only seems to return first element. When I run the same code at groovy command line, it naturally [iterates as groovy would expect](http://naleid.com/blog/2008/12/01/groovy-makes-iteration-easy). Is the .each{ } function getting overwritten somehow?

Comment: I doubt it...  does: `[[componentName:'Dashboard_Core'], [componentName:'Dashboard_Equities'], [componentName:'home']].each { println "adding $it.componentName" }` work as expected?  What about `['Dashboard_Core', 'Dashboard_Equities', 'home'].collect { [componentName: it] }.each { println "adding $it.componentName" }`?

Comment: First one does not, it only shows the first element as mine did.
Second one fails in the sandbox environment:
    org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: unclassified field java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry componentName

Comment: How old is the version of groovy on your servers? My money is on ancient...

Comment: I am pretty sure Pipeline uses the built-in groovy library for Jenkins. We are running Jenkins 1.642.3

Comment: Try printing it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876440/how-do-i-find-out-groovy-runtime-version-from-a-running-app

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `each` method on a closure does not yet work in Pipeline script. A fix is in progress. Meanwhile use a C-style `for` loop.

Comment: Or create a seperate method and make it @NonCPS

Comment: Issue is still not working (Pipeline Plugin 2.4). Does anyone know when this issue will be fixed?