# Why parallel from build flow plugin never ends

Tags: jenkins

We have one job that executes several other using build flow jenkins plugin.

main points of used flow DSL:

```
def parallelJobs = [];
jobParams.each { 
  ...
  parallelJobs.add({
    res = build(jobName
      , PARAM_NAME: param_value
      ... another_params ...
     )
   })
}
parallel(parallelJobs)
```

In log of this job I can see schedule and start of all added jobs, but not completion of them (most of them completed, but some just lost). If I check individual logs for not completed jobs they are really finished, but parent job doesn't see this, parallel never ends and everythings hangs forever.

For long time this job worked fine, but for now it hangs for every build. (There was several changes but for now it's difficult to find 
reason).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating a groovy list in Jenkins Pipeline DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360097/iterating-a-groovy-list-in-jenkins-pipeline-dsl)

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a version of Jenkins prior to 1.633? If you are, you're probably affected by this bug and need to upgrade Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-29888