# How can I add the next list to do a sum and avarage?

Tags: java, groovy, katalon-studio, webharvest

I got the following code:

```
    def arrayOfInts = [actual_speed_mobile_1.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_2.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_3.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_4.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_5.toInteger()]
    
    "this is **important** if we use removeAt"
    Collections.sort(arrayOfInts)
    
    def min = Collections.min(arrayOfInts);
    WebUI.comment("our min value is " + min.toString())
    
    def max = Collections.max(arrayOfInts);
    WebUI.comment("our max value is " + max.toString())
    
    WebUI.comment("our list of values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
    
    arrayOfInts.removeAt(0);
    WebUI.comment("our list of values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
    
    if (min != max) {
        arrayOfInts.removeAt(arrayOfInts.size() - 1);
        WebUI.comment("our list of values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
        }
    WebUI.comment("our values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
```

The output is:

```
    arrayOfInts = [actual_speed_mobile_1.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_2.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_3.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_4.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_5.toInteger()]
    
    Collections.sort(arrayOfInts)
    
    in = Collections.min(arrayOfInts)
    comment("our min value is " + min.toString())
    our min value is 74
    
    max = Collections.max(arrayOfInts)
    comment("our max value is " + max.toString())
    our max value is 86
    
    comment("our list of values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
    our list of values are [74, 82, 83, 84, 86]
   
    arrayOfInts.removeAt(0)
   comment("our list of values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
    our list of values are [82, 83, 84, 86]
    
    if (min != max)
    arrayOfInts.removeAt(arrayOfInts.size() - 1)
    
    comment("our list of values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
    
    our list of values are [82, 83, 84]
```

I want the list to do average I was thinking to add it into a new variable and transform it to inter but I got error:

```
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.toInterger() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    at Aspire_cashout.run(Aspire_cashout:115)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code can be rewritten in somewhat more idiomatic groovy as for example:

```
//def arrayOfInts = [actual_speed_mobile_1.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_2.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_3.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_4.toInteger(), actual_speed_mobile_5.toInteger()]
def strings = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
def ints = strings.collect { it as Integer}.sort()
println "ints: $ints"

ints.removeAt(0)
println "ints: $ints"

if (ints.min() != ints.max()) {
  // init returns a list of all elements except the last
  ints = ints.init()
}

println "ints: $ints"

println "average: ${ints.average()}"

def avg = ints.sum() / ints.size()
println "average: ${avg} (groovy < 3.x)"
```

where the [`iterable.average()`](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#average()) method was introduced in groovy 3.0. If you are running a version of groovy older than that, you can use the `ints.sum() / ints.size()` construct.

When executed (with groovy 3.x) the above code results in:

```
─➤ groovy -v
Groovy Version: 3.0.6 JVM: 11.0.10 Vendor: Amazon.com Inc. OS: Linux

─➤ groovy solution.groovy
ints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ints: [2, 3, 4, 5]
ints: [2, 3, 4]
average: 3
average: 3 (groovy < 3.x)

─➤
```

Other relevant methods on iterable: [init](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#init()), [tail](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#tail()), [head](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#head()), [last](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#last()).

Comment: Thank you! I use Katalon and Katalon uses groovy but I am not sure what version of groovy he uses.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876440/how-do-i-find-out-groovy-runtime-version-from-a-running-app

Comment: The version which I got on Katalon is: 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

I add this:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayOfInts.size(); i++)
        total = total + arrayOfInts[i];
        
    }
WebUI.comment("our values are " + arrayOfInts.toString())
def avarage = total/arrayOfInts.size();
println(avarage.toString())
```

Maybe I can help somneone